# Get values between curly braces c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, c#-4.0, split

I never used regex before. I was abel to see similar questions in forum but not exactly what im looking for

I have a string like following. need to get the values between curly braces

> Ex: "{name}{name@gmail.com}"

And i Need to get the following splitted strings.

> name and name@gmail.com

I tried the following and it gives me back the same string.

```
string s = "{name}{name@gmail.com}";
string pattern = "({})";
string[] result = Regex.Split(s, pattern);
```

Comment: This is quite a good tool for creating regex patterns/learning regex http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is using regex a must? In this particular example I would write:

```
s.Split(new char[] { '{', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: @FabianBigler I was under the impression that regex can easily achieve this, So i included Regex in the title :). I have changed the title now ;)

Comment: Wouldn't the proposed solution also take as correct a string such as `string s = "}name{name@gmail.com";`?

Comment: I voted too fast… This solution does not provide an answer. Consider input string : {name}blabla{name@gmail.com}, you’ll have also “blabla” in the array…

Answer (score 40):

Use `Matches` of `Regex` rather than `Split` to accomplish this easily:

```
string input = "{name}{name@gmail.com}";
var regex = new Regex("{(.*?)}");
var matches = regex.Matches(input);
foreach (Match match in matches) //you can loop through your matches like this
{
  var valueWithoutBrackets = match.Groups[1].Value; // name, name@gmail.com
  var valueWithBrackets = match.Value; // {name}, {name@gmail.com}
}
```

Comment: Interesting, i get matches with brackets. Why?
//my matches: {name}, {name@gmail.com}

Comment: @Georg Changed the answer accordingly. Included a group to display the value either with or without brackets. The difference to the other solutions is that Regex looks for matches, whereas the other answers are directly splitting the string.

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
string s = "{name}{name@gmail.com}";
s = s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2);// remove first and last characters
string pattern = "}{";// split pattern "}{"
string[] result = Regex.Split(s, pattern);
```

or

```
string s = "{name}{name@gmail.com}";
s = s.TrimStart('{');
s = s.TrimEnd('}');
string pattern = "}{";
string[] result = Regex.Split(s, pattern);
```

Comment: It works, but is there any way to get this result only using Regex pattern without using Substring ?

Comment: im wondering if there is any was to to get the rsult only with regex pattern without doing any other string manipulation ?

Comment: @Coder yes, take a look at my answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid regex and also account for non-formatted text (stuff not inside the curly braces), Split on '{' and then split each of those on '}':

```cs
string s = "Hi {firstName}, my name is {firstName}, {myLastName}";

IEnumerable<string> tokens = s
    .Split('{')
    .Where(t => t.Contains('}'))
    .Select(t => t.Split('}').First());

// This will yield "firstName", "firstName", "myLastName".

IEnumerable<string> distinctTokens = tokens.Distinct(); // To weed out duplicates.
```