# Getting value using regex

Tags: regex

how to get the value between first `{` and last `}` from a string which have multiple `{}`.

```
eg string:  ".....[object:{ ..{...{..}...}..}]"
```

My approach using C#:

```
line="abcd..efg..[object:{ ab{..c{d.}.e.}f....g}]"
string p = ".*\\[Object:{([A-Za-z{}]*)}\\]";
Regex r = new Regex(p);
Match m=r.match(line);
string value=m.Groups[1].Value.ToString();
```

Result should be:

```
value= ab{..c{d.}.e.}f....g
```

Comment: You should post ur attempts ,test string,expected result!!!!! seems more like a `chat` :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get values between curly braces c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379482/get-values-between-curly-braces-c-sharp) or [Regex to get string between curly braces “{I want what's between the curly braces}”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace)

Comment: @vks i'll keep that in mind from now on :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{.*}
```

or

```
(?<={).*(?=})
```

This should do the trick for you.See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/115)

```
string strRegex = @"{.*}";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @".....[object:{ ..{...{..}...}..}]";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
     // Add your code here
  }
}
```