# Format string with dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, format

Suppose I had the following code in **Python** (yes, this question is about c# this is just an example)

```py
string = "{entry1} {entry2} this is a string"
dictionary = {"entry1": "foo", "entry2": "bar"}

print(string.format(**dictionary))

# output is "foo bar this is just a string"
```

In this string, it would replace the {entry1} and {entry2} from the string to foo and bar using the `.format()`

Is there anyway I can replicate this EXACT same thing in C# (and also remove the curly braces) like the following code:

```cs
string str1 = "{entry1} {entry2} this a string";
Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = new() {
    {"entry1", "foo"},
    {"entry2", "bar"}
};

// how would I format this string using the given dict and get the same output?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for a dictionary and in it manipulate your string as per your need Like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static string ReplaceKeyInString(this Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, string inputString)
    {

        var regex = new Regex("{(.*?)}");
        var matches = regex.Matches(inputString);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            var valueWithoutBrackets = match.Groups[1].Value;
            var valueWithBrackets = match.Value;

            if(dictionary.ContainsKey(valueWithoutBrackets))
                inputString = inputString.Replace(valueWithBrackets, dictionary[valueWithoutBrackets]);
        }

        return inputString;
    }
}
```

Now use this extension method to convert given string to the expected string,

```
string input = "{entry1} {entry2} this is a string";
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> 
{ 
  { "entry1", "foo" }, 
  { "entry2", "bar" } 
};

var result = dictionary.ReplaceKeyInString(input);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

---

RegEx logic credit goes to [@Fabian Bigler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903124/fabian-bigler). Here is Fabian's answer:

[Get values between curly braces c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17379711/6299857)

---

**[Try online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SBRrXP)**

Answer (score 2):

using string interpolation you could do the following

```
    Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = new() {
    {"entry1", "foo"},
    {"entry2", "bar"}
    };
    string result = $"{dict1["entry1"]} {dict1["entry2"]} this is a string";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace values within `{...}` with a help of *regular expressions*:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string str1 = "{entry1} {entry2} this a string";

  Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = new() {
    { "entry1", "foo" },
    { "entry2", "bar" }
  };

  string result = Regex.Replace(str1, @"{([^}]+)}", 
      m => dict1.TryGetValue(m.Groups[1].Value, out var v) ? v : "???");

  // Let's have a look:
  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  foo bar this a string
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach (var d in dict) str1=str1.Replace("{"+d.Key+"}",d.Value);
```

or if you like the extensions

```
    Console.WriteLine(str1.FormatFromDictionary(dict));
    
public  static string FormatFromDictionary(this string str, Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
        foreach (var d in dict) str = str.Replace("{" + d.Key + "}", d.Value);
        return str;
}
```

You can use a string builder if there are may items to replace in one string

```
public  static string FormatFromDictionary(this string str, Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str, 100);
        foreach (var d in dict) sb.Replace("{" + d.Key + "}", d.Value);
        return sb.ToString();
}
```